# C# доступ к свойству устройства через WMI

Tags: c#, wmi

уважаемые программисты. Прошу помочь, ибо я уже путаюсь в изученном и найденном материале, а поставленную перед собой задачу решить охота.

**Цель:** программно снять флаг с "отключения устройства для экономии энергии" (вкладка "Управление электропитанием" в свойствах некоторых устройств) у сетевых адаптеров.
**Используется изначально:** VS 17, C#

**Чего я добился:** узнал о Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI, мудреный, но мощный инструмент, похоже). Заметил класс [Win32_NetworkAdapter](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/win32-networkadapter), но искомое свойство там не обнаружил. Ну и, по логике, оно же относится не только к сетевым адаптерам. Однако, все же [нашел искомое](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/wmi-and-the-power-management-tab) совершенно в других дебрях. Остался вопрос: как теперь все это соединить и сказать: "Эй, сетевые адаптеры! А ну-ка все пробуйте GUID_POWER_DEVICE_ENABLE сделать false!"

Или я вообще не туда уже ушел и все делается иначе, клац-клац и в продакшн? :(

**UPD:** было предложено искать значение в реестре. Явного значения так и не было найдено, однако пришло в голову, что все это возможно провернуть через PowerShell, с которым работал я крайне мало. Трудновато, когда не понимаю, какой путь наиболее правильный и рациональный. Продолжаю поиски решения.

Comment: Вы не дочитали найденную статью про guid.... Там в конце есть оговорка, что это значение нельзя изменить для загруженного драйвера устройства, поэтому оно хранится в реестре, чтобы вы могли поставить/снять галку когда угодно, а драйвер подхватил при его перезапуске. Осталось совсем чуть-чуть, найти guid устройства и найти соответствующую запись в реестре, опционально научиться перезапускать драйвер.

Comment: Хоо, и правда. Тогда на размышление есть новый алгоритм: программе следует найти все адаптеры, найти соответствующие ключи реестра, если есть нужное значение - изменить. Буду рыть в этом направлении, спасибо.